# How to incr/decr column values based on passed parameters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Looking to create a dynamic stored procedure for a single test-table where I can change values in one of the columns, based on arguments passed to it.

Example: I have one table where I want to be able to "move" movies (`MovieID`) from one store (`StoreID`) to another, and showcase that move in stock (`Movies_in_stock`). Once the stored procedure has run (and depending on arguments entered), it should show e.g. that 1 movie with `MovieID = 100` in `StoreID 1` has been moved to `StoreID 2` - `Movies_in_stock` has subsequently decreased for `StoreID = 1` and increased (plus a new row) for `StoreID = 2`.

Please see table changes below.

```
| StoreID | MovieID | Movies_in_stock |
|   1     |  100    |       10        |
|   2     |  200    |       20        |
|   3     |  300    |       50        |  
|   1     |  400    |      100        |
|   2     |  500    |        5        |
```

After running the stored procedure, I expect this data:

```
| StoreID | MovieID | Movies_in_stock |
|   1     |  100    |        9        |
|   2     |  200    |       20        |
|   3     |  300    |       50        |  
|   1     |  400    |      100        |
|   2     |  500    |        5        |
|   2     |  100    |        1        |
```

What I've done so far:

- Set parameters:

```
MovieID = @MovieID, StoreID = @StoreID_From , StoreID = @StoreID_To, Movies_in_stock = @Stock (optional param)
```

- Trying to figure out how to possibly combine `CASE` with `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Movies_in_stock = 
        (CASE WHEN @StoreID = x AND @StoreID = y 
                  THEN (Movies_in_stock = Movies_in_stock +/- @Movies_in_stock) 
                  ELSE 0 
         END)
WHERE @MovieID = z
```

Open and thankful for any suggestions/help/ideas/improvements received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are actually trying to do here is a merge.

- Construct a virtual source table of changes: the From store gets a negative quantity.
- Merge that into the existing table, inserting in cases where there is no row for that location and movie combination

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE MoveStock
    @MovieID int,
    @StoreID_From int,
    @StoreID_To int,
    @StockToMove int = 1;
AS

WITH Source AS (
    SELECT StoreID = @StoreID_To, DiffQty = @StockToMove
    UNION ALL
    SELECT @StoreID_From, (-@StockToMove)
),
Target AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM Table1
    WHERE MovieID = @MovieID
      AND StoreID IN (@StoreID_From, @StoreID_To)  -- this line for performance only, try without
)
MERGE Target t
USING Source s
   ON s.StoreID = t.StoreID
WHEN MATCHED AND t.Movies_in_stock + s.DiffQty <= 0
    THEN DELETE  -- decide whether you want this condition
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET Movies_in_stock += s.DiffQty
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (StoreID, MovieID, Movies_in_stock)
    VALUES (S.StoreID, @MovieID, s.DifQty)
;
```

Comment: this worked, thank you so much!